# how to get parent node index when parent node is inserted at runtime in treelist?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I've added parent node at runtime as

`TreeListNode parentNode1 = treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "BuiltIn Groups"}, null);`

But now i want to insert child node under particular parent node. In my application when user right click on particular parent node then i shown a menu & when user selects to insert new child node under selected parent node then i used the same `treeList1.AppendNode()` method but this method require second parameter as parent node index & i'm getting that parent node index when i insert parent node at run time.

Can u suggest something about this issue?

thanks.

Comment: try parentNode1.AppendNode(child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```
    TreeListNode parentNode = treeList1.AppendNode(..., null);
    TreeListNode childNode = treeList1.AppendNode(..., parentNode);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to insert a new child under the current selected node:

```
TreeNode parent = treeView.SelectedNode;

if (parent != null)
{
    treeList1.AppendNode(..., parent);
}
```